# Prometheus metrics are not matching with kubestate metrics in kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, kube-state-metrics

Metrics in Kubernetes Dashboard: [image]

kubectl top report:[image]

Metrics in Prometheus Grafana Dashboard: [image]

I installed Prometheus operator setup using helm chart prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack.
Can anyone explain me why there a difference in the metrics ? As both prometheus & kubernetes dashboard use kube-state-metrics. which one is better to use ?

Comment: What exact command do you use, what kind of query  did you apply using prometheus ? Please paste commands and arguments you have used.

Comment: Memory Usage Query in Grafana : sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace", container!="", image!=""}) by (pod)

Comment: Did you take a look https://github.com/lensapp/lens/issues/607 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that on the K8s dashboard you are looking at aggregated for 7 days, and on the grafana for the last value of the metric? But it can be something else there is too much info missing.
Are we talking about a pod or node? does kubectl top report something totally different?

Comment: added kubectl top snip, the metrics specified are for a POD